# How can I pick different locales for different locale categories

Tags: locale, system-settings

I would like to have different setting for various locales, so per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale I edited `/etc/default/locale`.

However, the file does not get picked up (after rebooting) and the settings from `System Settings>Langugage support` are used. (i.e. running `locales` and `cat /etc/default/locale` yields very different results). How can I force the system to use the setting from `/etc/default/locale`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should edit `~/.profile` (which overrides `~/.pam_environment`) instead of `/etc/default/locale` to achieve what you want. Please see *System Settings -> Language Support -> Help -> Advanced format settings* for an example.